# How do I exclude soft deleted records in aggregate function?

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

I am trying to get all the record in a table `order by` **review** and **review count**. I need to include reviews not soft deleted (i.e. deleted_at field in `reviews` table not null), this I have done by using `whereNull` clause. At this point I got the desired result; But the issue is, when the table has reviews and they all are soft deleted, the record is not displayed.

```
$restaurantBranch = $restaurantBranch->leftJoin('reviews', 'restaurant_branches.id', '=', 'reviews.restaurant_id')
                    ->selectRaw('restaurant_branches.*,count(reviews.rating) as rev_num, avg(reviews.rating) as average_rating')
                    ->whereNUll("reviews.deleted_at")
                    ->orderBy('average_rating', "desc")->orderBy('rev_num', "desc")
                    ->groupBY('restaurant_branches.id');
```

How do I display the records?

Comment: create a scope and pass in query.

Comment: Can you please provide some info on what the snippet would look like?  Thanks

Comment: Did anyone found the answer?